# Dual boot Windows 7 error

Tags: boot, windows, updates, data-recovery

I had Ubuntu 13.10 and Win7 getting along fine together... then a Windows update failed.  Now I can't boot Windows.  Linux is working fine.

All data appears good in the Windows partition.  I don't want to lose this data but I want Windows to work again.

I used the Windows recovery and it failed.

Any way to fix Windows through Linux?

Comment: what version of windows you use ?

Comment: Title of the question says Windows 7
That really should make it obvious that I use Windows 7...

Answer (score 0):

Please followed this link to Repair Master Boot Record MBR of windows 8.
[click here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows)

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: Title of the question says Windows 7

Not Windows 8